# does it work to nest media queries inside keyframes for CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

This is my generated CSS after running this in my extra css under components

```
@layer components {
  @keyframes alt-pop-enter {
    from {
      @apply translate-y-2 opacity-0 sm:translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-2;
    }
    to {
      @apply translate-y-0 opacity-100 sm:translate-x-0;
    }
  }
```

this produces the following as generated css

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    --tw-translate-y: 0.5rem;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 0;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    from {
      --tw-translate-y: 0px;
      --tw-translate-x: 0.5rem;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }
  }

  to {
    --tw-translate-y: 0px;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 1;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    to {
      --tw-translate-x: 0px;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }
  }
}
```

Am I right to say that the media queries will not be executed since they are not legal inside keyframes?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should change to this instead

As state in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.php, the valid value are

- 0-100%
- from (same as 0%)
- to (same as 100%)

```css
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    --tw-translate-y: 0.5rem;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    --tw-translate-y: 0px;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  @keyframes alt-pop-enter {
    from {
      --tw-translate-y: 0px;
      --tw-translate-x: 0.5rem;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }

    to {
      --tw-translate-x: 0px;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so the answer to the question "the media queries will not be executed since they are not legal inside keyframes?" is yes, they will not be executed because they are not legal inside keyframes. Yes?

Comment: @KimStacks yea, as you can check this documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes, as it values only support `<custom-ident>,  from, to ,<percentage>`